# How can i save previous value of variable in Matlab Function

Tags: matlab, simulink

Hello I would like to know how to save the previous value of an output variable in a matlab function.

```
function y = fcn(x,d,yp)
yp=0;  %here I want to initialize this value just at the start of simulation
if (x-yp<=d)
    y=x;
else 
    y=yp + d;
end
yp=y;  % here i want to load output value
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a persistent variable is the correct way to go, but as you found out, you cannot use `varargin` in a MATLAB Function block. The trick is to check whether the variable is empty or not, as in:

```
function y = fcn(x,d,yp)

persistent yp

if isempty(yp)
   yp=0;  %only if yp is empty, i.e. at the beginning of the simulation
end

if (x-yp<=d)
    y=x;
else 
    y=yp + d;
end

yp=y;  % here i want to load output value
```

Answer (score 4):

Make `yp` `persistent`

```
function y = fcn(x,d,varargin)
persistent yp 

if nargin>2 
   yp = varargin{1};
end
...
yp=y;
end
```

Since `yp` is persistent now next time you will call the function `yp` will already hold the value of `y` you calculated previously. The only problem is not to override it by `yp=0` as you have currently.

I replaced `yp` in the list of function arguments with `varargin` which holds optional arguments. The first time you call `fcn` you should call it as `y = fcn(x,d,0)`, where the zero will be passed to `yp` inside the function. Next time you should call it without the third argument not to override the value `yp` holds (i.e. `y = fcn(x,d)`.

Comment: Thank you but I forgot to mention that i am using Matlab function Simulink block which can't use this method. i get error message: Top-level function cannot have varargin.

Comment: @MarcelReisinger As one possible work around you can make `yp` `global` instead of `persistent`. Then before the loop from which you call `fcn` you would initialize it to zero (or whatever you like) `yp=0` and that's it. But make sure you never touch `yp` again (outside `fcn`). Then in `fcn` delete `varargin` and the `if nargin` block.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [persistent](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html) variables, you can also save the value in a nested function and return a handle to that function:

```
function fun = fcn(yp0)

    yp = yp0;   % declared in the main function scope

    fun = @(x,d) update(x,d); % function handle stores the value a yp above and updates below.

    function y = update(x,d)
        if (x-yp<=d)
            y=x;
        else
            y=yp + d;
        end
        yp = y;     % updated down here
    end

end
```

And then you would use it like

```
fun = fcn(yp0);
y   = fun(x,d);
```

I use this instead of persistent variables when I notice a performance increase from not checking the initialization of persistent variables.

Comment: Thank you but I forgot to mention that i am using Matlab function Simulink block which can't use this method. I get error message :Nested functions are not supported.